# How make use of StreamInsight to watch Table for any changes

Tags: c#, streaminsight

I have started learning CEP recently. I'm planning to implement these StreamInsigh CEP in my project

My application is like this:
I need to write an application to watch Table for newly inserted rows.Need to do operations on these new rows.

Can we acheive this without using Sql Dependency.
or Can i use SqlDependecy+CEP.

Please suggest me with best suited soltion

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a StreamInsight solution for you, but assuming that you can perform these operations in SQL, would a trigger on inserted not solve your problem?